# When iterating through large set of string set, for loop received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault

Tags: c++

I have a loop through a very large set of names below got segment fault, where is the issue ?

```
   void test(std::set<std::wstring> *names)
    {
        std::set<std::wstring>::iterator itr;
        for (itr = names->begin(); itr != names->end(); ++itr)
        {
           std::wstring name = *itr;

        }

    }
```

Error:

> ```
> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
> 0x00007fff84b62c54 in std::__1::basic_string<wchar_t, std::__1::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::__1::allocator<wchar_t>>::basic_string(std::__1::basic_string<wchar_t, std::__1::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::__1::allocator<wchar_t> > const&)> () from /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
> ```

Comment: Does the code terminate after iterating for a while? Or it terminates right after entering the loop? Are you sure the passed set is not NULL?

Comment: terminated after the second iteration of the loop. only name with length not 0 will be in the set.

Answer (score 0):

No problem with the code you show, as demonstrated by this [MWE live at Ideone](http://ideone.com/npwoeh):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void test(std::set<std::wstring> *names) {
     std::set<std::wstring>::iterator itr;
     for (itr = names->begin(); itr != names->end(); ++itr) {
           std::wstring name = *itr;
     }
}

int main() {
    std::set<std::wstring> s{L"aasdasd", L"badsasd"};
    test(&s);
    return 0;
}
```

Therefore the issue is somewhere else in your code which is not shown. I'd suggest using a debugger such as [gdb](http://www.unknownroad.com/rtfm/gdbtut/), to find what is going on. E.g. on a Linux system:

1. compile with -g flag `g++ -g main.cpp -o main`
2. load in gdb with `gdb main`
3. `run` > read the stack trace

As a side note, a for loop would be nicer, and if you don't plan to modify `names` pass it by const reference ([example here on Ideone](http://ideone.com/VpW6Ml)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void test(const std::set<std::wstring> &names) {
    for (auto&& name : names) {
        std::wcout << name << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    std::set<std::wstring> s{L"aasdasd", L"badsasd"};
    test(s);
    return 0;
}
```